# Can a batsman hit a six on dead ball?

Tags: cricket

If batsman hits a six on dead-ball,It'll be counted in total runs or not? 
I have seen in a [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooC1I-BdZZE) that Australian player is hitting a six on a dead ball and Umpire is giving sign of 6 runs. How runs can be counted on a **dead-ball?**

Answer (score 2):

The video example which you gave involves a ball which should have been called as a no-ball. If it was, the batsman is entitled to hit it anywhere they like. That ball was not dead but because it bounced twice before it reached the popping crease, it was a no-ball.

Once a ball has been called dead, the batsman cannot hit it so therefore cannot hit it for six.

Answer (score 1):

A batsman cannot score any run on dead ball bcos umpire declare a dead ball on which no action  can be attempted.